# Mapping objects between the domain and database

Tags: n-tier-architecture

When mapping between database objects and domain objects, which "layer" of my application should this functionality reside in?

Say I have:

- `DAL` - has a reference to core domain
- `Service` - has a reference to `DAL` and core domain

Where is the mapping more appropriately placed in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAL would be a good place in this scenario, as it already references your core where your domain entities should live. It can do the fetching of data, and convert it to domain objects before returning.

In this way you can encapsulate the knowledge of the DB objects to the DAL layer, which is a good thing. If you ever need to change your DB out, you only need to modify this layer. The rest of the application only knows about the Domain.

Comment: This solution fits better with my architecture I believe.  My core domain defines interfaces for the repositories and services which my UI and DAL implement.  It being an implementation of the ports and adapters pattern, or onion architecture if you will.

Comment: Yes, based on your description I gathered that your architecture was more of an onion architecture, rather than the traditional n-tier. This solution allows you to keep the knowledge of your concrete implementations abstracted from the core of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the principle that says a layer only need to know about the next layer down (idea taken from the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)) the best practice would be to place the translation code in the Service Layer.

However, as the core domain could be considered itself another layer in the middle of your service and data access layer, and considering the service layer talks directly with the DAL (breaking the LoD principle), probably the simpler and more pragmatic solution (as @wblanks says) could be to put the translation code in the data access layer.

Comment: Whilst I agree with and try to adhere to the LoD, considering both layers are aware of the core domain (for interface definitions of entities and repositories) is this still applicable?